# Compare two list with Java-8

Tags: java

I want to compare two lists (eastList and westList). `EastList` will contain the value  `0` and `westList` will contain the value is `1`. The returned value should be `5`. Code works true. Can I write second for loop with streams? How can write this code snipped with Java 8 features for efficient code? Please help. Thanks...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public int solution(int[] A) {
    List<Integer> eastList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> westList = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if(A[i] == 0) {
            eastList.add(i);
        }
        else {
            westList.add(i);
        }
    }

    for(int m = 0; m < eastList.size(); m++) {
        for(int n = 0; n < westList.size(); n++) {
            if(eastList.get(m) < westList.get(n)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution solution = new Solution();
    int[] A = {0,1,0,1,1};    
    solution.solution(A);
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your code supposed to do? Please describe it and add more details to the question other than asking someone else to do your assignment :)

Comment: I am trying compare two list. but i am using old ways. i want to write this loop with java-8. All code snipped is above

Comment: Good news: your code still works with Java 8, no need to change it.

Comment: The given code is very clear and understandable. What makes you think the Java-8 (streams?) approach will give you any advantages?

Comment: I think for loop maybe write with streams.

Comment: I mean, you could use a for-each loop or the forEach method on Stream, but I don't see the point of streams

Comment: @zeynep: This code **is Java 8**. It is even **Java 14**. If you mean usage of particular *other* syntax, write this in your question.

Comment: I refreshed my question.

Comment: Could you explain what your three arrays are? A, eastList, and westList?

Comment: Would you pls explain your question in detail? What is it for? What kind of problem do you try to solve?

Comment: I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

For Java9 and above you can use `dropWhile`

```
eastList.stream().map(
  east -> westList.stream().dropWhile(west -> west <= east).count()
).sum()
```

And (in my opinion) stream-based code is more expressive because `dropWhile` and `count` calls exactly describe what we are doing with `east` and `westList`

**UPDATE: fixed as per Rahul's comment**

Comment: A label is not necessary here. Simply using `break` would suffice.

Comment: Yes but I like the expressiveness of `continue eastLoop:`, especially if this expressiveness costs me nothing ;)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov It costs simplicity and readability of the code. Labels are useful for complex structures. In simple cases like here they are nothing but noise.

Comment: it is highly opinionated, do not want to participate holy war

Comment: ```eastLoop: for(int east : eastList) {
    for(int west : westList) {
        if(east < west) {
            count++;
        } else {
            continue eastLoop; // east and west lists are ordered
        }
    }
}  ``` well did you check the piece of code there is problem it would be return the count ```3``` not  ```5```  @Alexander Pavlov

Comment: when eastList is contain  ```2``` and westList is contain ```1 ``` , if block return false than in else block you are continuing to eastList instead of scanning the complete the westList for rest values.